# Defaults with Python Cmd interpreter

Tags: python, argparse, read-eval-print-loop

I'm working with an existing Apache Open Source python code base (Cassandra [CQLSH](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/pylib/cqlshlib/cqlshmain.py)) using the [cmd.Cmd](https://docs.python.org/3/library/cmd.html) class for an interpreter shell. Like many Shells, you can configure defaults in a dot-rc file (.cqlshrc), pass them as arguments on the command line to the shell, or, use default in a `__init__` constructor.

The problem is each phase attempts to set the defaults with global constants. This means each level needs to both know the defaults and once set, bypass the constructor (**init**).  It has become a [Big Ball of Mud](https://s3.amazonaws.com/systemsandpapers/papers/bigballofmud.pdf). Separation of responsibilities is not straightforward.

I'm looking for a better [Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) here. Since Cmd is a core Python library, someone must have implemented it well with cmd line args and .rc defaults.
Example:

```
1. Global constant
DEFAULT_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 10

2. Cmd line arg
parser.add_argument("--connect-timeout", default=DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, dest='connect_timeout',
                    help='Specify the connection timeout in seconds (default: %(default)s seconds).')

3. read config file (.cqlshrc)
argvalues.connect_timeout = option_with_default(configs.getint, 'connection', 'timeout', DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS)

4. Constructor default
def __init__(self, ... connect_timeout=DEFAULT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS, ...):
```

.

Collaborators on [CASSANDRA-18914](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-18914) welcome.